# Jython: syntax check available?

Tags: python, java, jython

I am using Jython for a simple Python script task inside a Java app.

```java
Properties ps = new Properties();
ps.put ("python.console.encoding", "UTF-8");
ps.put ("python.import.site", "false");
PythonInterpreter.initialize (System.getProperties (), ps, new String [0]);
this.pi = new PythonInterpreter ();

String pycode = "print \"abc\"";
pi.exec (pycode);
```

This works, but now I need to think of a way to check the code before it is executed.

I tried `pi.compile`:

```java
PyCode pc = pi.compile (pycode);
pi.exec (pc);
```

But I do not see any effect with that regarding my problem.

Method compile produces a result even if exec fails afterwards (e.g. wrong syntax).

Comment: May I ask why you need to check the python syntax before execution? Can't you just check the code separately before adding it to your program? Why is letting `exec` just fail not ok?

Comment: Maybe pycode is something a user put in the app before and he wants to have an indication if it is ok or not - just before executing. The same is true for a development-environment.